# Wordpress Admin - Function not defined?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm having problems trying to call a Javascript function from an enqueued javascript file used whilst editing Wordpress pages.  I have created a simple meta box with some AJAX hyperlinks that I want to be able to call functions from the Javascript file (pretty simply stuff but I keep getting error "blah(1) is not defined".

HTML CONTAINED IN METABOX:

```
<a href="#" class="delete_pimg" id="pimg_1" onclick="blah(1);return false;">Delete Item</a>
```

JS:

```
function blah(theid){

if ( confirm("Are you sure you wish to remove this image (Note: Images are not removed from the Media Library)?") ) {

    var data = {
    action: 'myajax-delete',
    imgid: theid
    };

    jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {

        //Parse the JSON Object
        var object = jQuery.parseJSON(response);

        if ( response.status == 'true' )
        {
            jQuery('#file_' + theid + '_row').remove(); //remove TR
            alert('Image removed from this portfolio');
        }else{
            alert('Sorry, that image could not removed right now, please reload the page and try again.');  
        }

    });
```

*Note:  The PHP server side code works fine and responds absolutely as expected to my manual Posts.  The javascript file is definitely present and being downloaded by the browser as expected.*

If I use the following line of code below, the AJAX works (so I know the JS is OK) but I need to be able to call the function by name rather use a selector. I'm very keen to work out why I can't call a simple function!!!!

```
jQuery('.delete_pimg').click(function() { ^Above code^ }
```

Just to re-cap the error I get when the link is clicked:  **'blah(1) is not defined'**

I hope I've explained this clearly - if not, please give me a shout :)

Comment: You show both inline and jQuery code to call function `blah` in your question. Neither work? One works? Which one do you want to use?

Comment: Hi - I want the inline version to work.  Everytime I click the link I get a message on the console "blah(1) is not defined".

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a syntax error in your js block? Can you execute blah from console?

Comment: JS block seems fine, if I use jQuery .click, the JS executes fine but I need to be able to execute using inline. I cannot execute from console, tried that one already.. :(  Even if I had a really simple bit of code like function blah(){alert('This works!');}  that still does the same thing.

Comment: If you can't execute your function from console then something is wrong with your page. You will have to post a link so that someone can take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok Basically - I could not get this to work.  My javascript is absolutely fine, so In order to call my own functions, I declared them within the page itself rather than calling in a JS file.  This seems to work and my code executed with no errors straight away.

I.e

```
<script type="text/javascript">function blah(id){alert("This Works Nicely!");}</script>
```

A work around but at least solved my problem anyway.

*Wipes sweat from forehead*

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue where `blah() is not defined`, and found out I needed to have the enqueued js file just define the function, instead of wrapped with a `jQuery(document).ready(function($) { function blah(param){[...]} })`.

Here's what my code looks like now, which got everything working for me:

## Inside of functions.php

(short snippet within my file)

```
function blah_init() {
  # Want this on all pages
  # Queue JS and CSS
  wp_enqueue_script(
    'blah-file', // handle  
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/blah-file.js', // source
    array('jquery'), // registered script handles this script depends on
    '1.0', // version
    true // true = in footer, false (or blank) = in <head>
  );
} 
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'blah_init');
```

## Inside of blah-file.js

(this is the full contents of the file)

```
//jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    function blah(param) {
      console.log('Blah triggered: ', param);
    } 
//})
```

## Inside of header.php and footer.php

(short snippet where I output some link, such as social link)

```
<!-- Ignore the href, this has nothing to do with getting this to work -->
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="blah("facebook")">Facebook</a>
```

Comment: If this solution doesn't work, you "might" need to use `add_action('init', 'blah_init');` instead of `add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'blah_init');`, or something similar (if you need this function in your admin interface)